# How to tell what triggered jQuery focus()?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an input field and a button. It is necessary that when the button is clicked the input field gets focus.

I need the behaviour to be slightly different depending on whether the input field was focused manually by the user or if it was focused due the button being clicked.

It seems this would be relatively simple, but I couldn't come up with a solution so far. Any ideas very welcome.

```
$("button").click(function() {
    target_input = $("input");
    target_input.focus();
});

$("input").focus(function() {
    // if focus done manually by user
    //    do something
    // if focus done via button
    //    do something else
});
```

Comment: You can use trigger instead of focus() and set extra params http://api.jquery.com/trigger/ . In focus event you can read extra params

Comment: Couldn't get it to work actually...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution that uses no extra variables, instead it checks the event.

```
$("button").click(function() {
    target_input = $("input");
    target_input.focus();
});

$("input").focus(function(e) {
    // if focus done manually by user
    //    do something
    // if focus done via button
    //    do something else

   if(e.originalEvent.relatedTarget){
      // only from button events
   }

   // here is from all events
});
```

this `e.originalEvent.relatedTarget` will return null if we didn't use the button to originate the focus.
remember to add `e` to the function.

Answer (score 0):

You *should be able to* use [`Event.isTrusted`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/isTrusted) for this:

> The isTrusted read-only property of the Event interface is a boolean
>   that is true when the event was generated by a user action, and false
>   when the event was created or modified by a script or dispatched via
>   dispatchEvent.

```
$("input").focus(function(e) {
    if(e.isTrusted) {...} else {...}
});
```

As noted in the comments, neither IE nor Safari like this.

Comment: It's not supported in IE and Safari

Answer (score 0):

This works without global variables and it is cross-browser working solution:

```js
$('button').click(function () {
  $(this).prev('input').focus()
})

$('input').click(function (e) { // yes, listen to click instead
   // original event exists only if input was clicked directly
  if (e.originalEvent) {
    console.log('manually triggered')
  }
})
```

```html
<div style="background-color: yellow;">
  <input type="text">
  <button>Focus input</button>
  <br>
  <input type="text">
  <button>Focus input</button>
</div>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/jquery"></script>
```